# How to filter data using SQL functions

Tags: sql

In my risk codes column, the rows look like these below

```
31
31 22 33 44
22 31 44 66
55 31 43 56
312 311 453 5678
```

So I should filter rows having 31 in it.. I need to get rows having 31 from the 2 digit code sequence rows itself not the row 312 311 453 5678. how do i do this..? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is a horrible design.  It looks like you are storing *multiple* values in a single *column*.  That is not the SQLish way to store multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Where ' '+YourField+' ' Like '% 31 %''
```

Notice that we prepend and append spaces on yourfield and within the Like string

Comment: @colonelclick Just a quick fix for an unfortunate structure.  I've inherited far worse.